# TypeScript with requirejs cannot find module error

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd

I am migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript. The existing JavaScript uses  requirejs for module loading, and I would like to do the same in TypeScript.

I have one module that is throwing "cannot find module" errors from its `import` statements when I compile.  I have the correct `<reference/>` tags, and the references modules will work at runtime as expected.  However, I would like to get these erroneous compiler errors out of my Error List window.

Here is the basic file structure of this module and its references:

```
root/
    helper.ts
    ui/
       uiModule.ts //This module is throwing the error
       panels/
           panel1.ts //The import of this module throws the error
```

The top of `uiModule` looks like this:

```
///<reference path="../helper.ts"/>
///<reference path="panels/panel1.ts"/>

import helper = require("Helper");
import panel1 = require("Panel1");
```

All of the modules are setup as single classes, like this:

```
//references and imports...
class MyClass {
    //Methods...
}

export = MyClass;
```

All filenames and `import` aliases start with lowercase; all class names start with uppercase.

The "cannot find module" errors seem to only be happening when one module references another in a deeper folder.  If I change the `import` statement to `require("Panels/panel1"), the compiler error goes away, but it fails at runtime.

How can I correctly make this error stop showing up?  I have a config file for requirejs.  Can I point the language service to that file to resolve module references?  I would really like to decouple references from file paths at design time as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, for the class definitions, you can update them to look like so.

```
export class MyClass {
    // TO-DO
}
```

As for the require statements, it's normal for the compiler to tell you they are cannot be found.

So given your file structure your imports should look like this:

```
import helper = require("../helper");
import panel1 = require("./panels/panel1");
```

or

```
// remember you can have a file with multiple exported objects
// or and 'index.ts' file inside a folder which exports multiple files
// by using the import syntax you can choose what to import from that module

import { helper } from '../helper';
import { panel1 } from './panels/panel1';
```

this should solve your current issues.

Example project I'm working on with TS for help:

https://github.com/vladjerca/imgstry/tree/feature/typescript_port

More on the subject:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score -1):

Don't use relative paths i.e.

"../../helper".

Always use absolute paths from your project folder i.e. 
"app/components/Helper"

Also don't put a / in front of the filepath as that can cause issues.

Don't use //references, use

```
import { myClass } from 'app/components/Helper';
```

This will also help requirejs find class references easier when bundling the js.

Vlad is also correct, just change your class definition too...

```
export class Helper {
    [...]
}
```

you don't need the export = Helper statement at the end of your file.